# Python ignores SIGINT in multithreaded programs - how to fix that?

Tags: python

I have Python 2.6 on MacOS X and a multithread operation. Following test code works fine and shuts down app on Ctrl-C:

```
import threading, time, os, sys, signal
def SigIntHandler( signum, frame ) :
  sys.exit( 0 )
signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, SigIntHandler )
class WorkThread( threading.Thread ) :
  def run( self ) :
    while True :
      time.sleep( 1 )
thread = WorkThread()
thread.start()
time.sleep( 1000 )
```

But if i change only one string, adding some real work to worker thread, the app will never terminate on Ctrl-C:

```
import threading, time, os, sys, signal
def SigIntHandler( signum, frame ) :
  sys.exit( 0 )
signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, SigIntHandler )
class WorkThread( threading.Thread ) :
  def run( self ) :
    while True :
      os.system( "svn up" ) # This is really slow and can fail.
      time.sleep( 1 )
thread = WorkThread()
thread.start()
time.sleep( 1000 )
```

Is it possible to fix it, or python is not intended to be used with threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things which may be causing your problem:

1. The Ctrl-C is perhaps being caught by `svn`, which is ignoring it.
2. You are creating a thread which is a non-daemon thread, then just exiting the process. This will cause the process to wait until the thread exits - which it never will. You need to either make the thread a daemon or give it a way to terminate it and `join()` it before exiting. While it always seems to stop on my Linux system, MacOS X behaviour may be different.

Python works well enough with threads :-)

**Update:** You could try using `subprocess`, setting up the child process so that  file handles are not inherited, and setting the child's stdin to subprocess.PIPE.

Comment: "The Ctrl-C is perhaps being caught by svn, which is ignoring it" - very interesting. Is it any way i can start "svn up" from my python code so input is going to python, not to svn?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on Threads with Python but quickly reading the docs leads to a few conclusions.

1) Calling `os.system()` spawns a new subshell and is not encouraged. Instead the subprocess module should be used. http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system

2) The `threading` module doesn't seem to give a whole lot of control to the threads, maybe try using the `thread` module, at least there is a `thread.exit()` function. Also from the `threading` docs [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#thread-objects) it says that dummy threads may be created, which are always alive and daemonic, furthermore

```
"… the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left."
```

So, I would imagine that the least you need to do is signal the currently running threads that they need to exit, before exiting the main thread, or joining them on ctrl-c to allow them to finish (although this would obviously be contradictory to ctrl-c), or perhaps just using the `subprocess` module to spawn the `svn up` would do the trick.

Comment: "The threading module doesn't seem to give a whole lot of control to the threads, maybe try using the thread module" - `threading` is based on `thread`, they are actually the same :(

Answer (score 2):

You likely do not need threads at all.

Try using Python's `subprocess` module, or even Twisted's [process support](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html).